# XSLT 1.0 Find unique node with Highest value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, transformation, xslt-grouping

I am beginner in XSLT 1.0. I am facing an issue when i tried to find unique node with Highest value.

**Source XML:**

```
<Response>
    <Flight>
        <From>A</From>
        <To>B</To>
        <Passengers>
            <Passenger>
                <Fare>200</Fare>
                <Fee>15</Fee>
                <Type>ADT</Type>
            </Passenger>
            <Passenger>
                <Fare>200</Fare>
                <Fee>15</Fee>
                <Type>ADT</Type>
            </Passenger>
            <Passenger>
                <Fare>150</Fare>
                <Fee>15</Fee>
                <Type>CHD</Type>
            </Passenger>
        </Passengers>
    </Flight>
    <Flight>
        <From>B</From>
        <To>A</To>
        <Passengers>
            <Passenger>
                <Fare>250</Fare>
                <Fee>25</Fee>
                <Type>ADT</Type>
            </Passenger>
            <Passenger>
                <Fare>250</Fare>
                <Fee>25</Fee>
                <Type>ADT</Type>
            </Passenger>
            <Passenger>
                <Fare>100</Fare>
                <Fee>25</Fee>
                <Type>CHD</Type>
            </Passenger>
        </Passengers>
    </Flight>
</Response>
```

As shown in above XML, There is a round trip result for A-B origin destination and i am going to purchase tickets for both the flights.
i need to calculate total fare, fee (whichever is highest from both the Flights) and its total price.

**Expected Output:**

```
<Result>
    <PassengerGroup TotalFare="1150" TotalFee="75" TotalPrice="1225"/>
</Result>
```

Here,

- `TotalFare` is sum of all the `Fare` tag.
- `TotalFee` is greater value of each passenger type multiply by no of passenger of that type.
- e.g. For ADT greater Fee value is 25 and number of ADT is 2 so total Fee for ADT is 50.
     For CHD greater Fee value is 25 and number of CHD is 1 so total Fee for CHD is 25.
     That makes final total fee = 75.
- `TotalPrice` is sum of `ToatalFare` and `TotalFee` attribute.

I've tried with below XSLT.

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <xsl:element name="Result">
            <xsl:element name="PassengerGroup">
                <xsl:attribute name="TotalFare">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Flight/Passengers/Passenger/Fare)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="TotalFee">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Flight/Passengers/Passenger[not(Type=preceding::Passenger/Type)]/Fee)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="TotalFee">
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//Flight/Passengers/Passenger/Fare) + sum(//Flight/Passengers/Passenger/Fee)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and got the below output.

**Output:**

```
<Result>
  <PassengerGroup TotalFare="1150" TotalFee="30" TotalPrice="1270"/>
</Result>
```

`TotalFee` is not calculated correctly. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: You say that the number of ADT passengers is 2, but it actually is 4 ... ??? Please, edit the question and correct.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - No of ADT passengers is 2. The Source XML shoes different prices of ADT on different Flight. First `Flight` tag shows that if you travel with this Flight it will charge 200+15=215, second `Flight` shows that if you travel with this Flight it will charge 250+25=275.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exslt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="kPassenger" match="Passenger" use="Type" />

  <!-- The passenger nodes from just the first flight, so we can count how many of 
       each type there are -->
  <xsl:variable name="passengers" select="Response/Flight[1]/Passengers/Passenger" />

  <xsl:template match="Response">
    <xsl:variable name="totalFare" select="sum(Flight/Passengers/Passenger/Fare)" />
    <xsl:variable name="feeByPassenger">
      <xsl:apply-templates 
         select="$passengers[generate-id() = 
                             generate-id(key('kPassenger', Type)[1])]"
         mode="fee" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="totalFee" 
                  select="sum(exslt:node-set($feeByPassenger)/*/@value)" />

    <Result>
      <PassengerGroup TotalFare="{$totalFare}" TotalFee="{$totalFee}" 
                      TotalPrice="{$totalFare + $totalFee}" />
    </Result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Passenger" mode="fee">
    <xsl:variable name="maxFee">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kPassenger', Type)/Fee">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fee value="{$maxFee * count($passengers[Type = current()/Type])}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Fee">
    <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Result>
  <PassengerGroup TotalFare="1150" TotalFee="75" TotalPrice="1225" />
</Result>
```